# Is it possible to refresh parent window of fancybox iframe without closing iframe popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, fancybox

I have product detail page within `fancybox iframe`. When I used to add product into cart, I have to update cart notification which is in parent window of iframe so I want to reload parent window without close iframe popup.

Please help me.

Comment: Not possible, the iframe is contained in the page html, reloading the parent page will simply fetch a fresh one. You might want to look into other options

Comment: It's possible as long as the content to be refreshed in the parent page is ajax content, but definitively not possible if you want to reload the whole page